# Create one hot encoded vector from category list in Spark

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, data-science

If I have data containing 5 categories (A,B,C,D,E) and a dataset of customers where each customer can belong to one, many or none of the categories. How can I take a data set like this:

```
id, categories
1 , [A,C]
2 , [B]
3 , []
4 , [D,E]
```

and transform the categories column to one hot encoded vectors, like this

```
id, categories, encoded
1 , [A,C]     , [1,0,1,0,0]
2 , [B]       , [0,1,0,0,0]
3 , []        , [0,0,0,0,0]
4 , [D,E]     , [0,0,0,1,1]
```

Has anyone found a simple way to do this in spark?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something very easy to do, which is somewhat the same is using a CountVectorizerModel

```
val df = spark.createDataFrame(Seq(
  (1, Seq("A","C")),
  (2, Seq("B")),
  (3, Seq()),
  (4, Seq("D","E")))
).toDF("id", "category")

val cvm = new CountVectorizerModel(Array("A","B","C","D","E"))
  .setInputCol("category")
  .setOutputCol("features")

cvm.transform(df).show()

/*
+---+--------+-------------------+
| id|category|           features|
+---+--------+-------------------+
|  1|  [A, C]|(5,[0,2],[1.0,1.0])|
|  2|     [B]|      (5,[1],[1.0])|
|  3|      []|          (5,[],[])|
|  4|  [D, E]|(5,[3,4],[1.0,1.0])|
+---+--------+-------------------+
*/
```

This isn't exactly like what you had wanted, but the feature vector will tell you what Categories exist in your data. For instance in row 1, [0,2] corresponds to the first and 3rd element of the dictionary, or "A" and "C" as written there.

Answer (score 7):

To achieve your desired output you can extend [Stephen Carman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4351210/stephen-carman) answer with Spark's UDF (*user-defined functions*):

```
// Prepare training documents from a list of (id, text, label) tuples.
val data = spark.createDataFrame(Seq(
  (0L, Seq("A", "B")),
  (1L, Seq("B")),
  (2L, Seq.empty),
  (3L, Seq("D", "E"))
)).toDF("id", "categories")

// Get distinct tags array
val tags = data
  .flatMap(r ⇒ r.getAs[Seq[String]]("categories"))
  .distinct()
  .collect()
  .sortWith(_ < _)

val cvmData = new CountVectorizerModel(tags)
  .setInputCol("categories")
  .setOutputCol("sparseFeatures")
  .transform(data)

val asDense = udf((v: Vector) ⇒ v.toDense)

cvmData
  .withColumn("features", asDense($"sparseFeatures"))
  .select("id", "categories", "features")
  .show()
```

Which will give you desired output

```
+---+----------+-----------------+
| id|categories|         features|
+---+----------+-----------------+
|  0|    [A, B]|[1.0,1.0,0.0,0.0]|
|  1|       [B]|[0.0,1.0,0.0,0.0]|
|  2|        []|[0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0]|
|  3|    [D, E]|[0.0,0.0,1.0,1.0]|
+---+----------+-----------------+
```