# How to use one-hot encoding or get_dummies for pyspark with lists as values in column?

Tags: python, pandas, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a spark dataframe:

```
+-----------+--------------------+
|columnIndex|               lists|
+-----------+--------------------+
|          1|[1.0,2.0]           |
|          2|[2.0]               |
|          3|[1.0]               |
|          4|[1.0,3.0]           |
+-----------+--------------------+
```

I need to get the following after one-hot encoding or get_dummies:

```
+-----------+--------------------+---+---+---+
|columnIndex|               lists|1.0|2.0|3.0|
+-----------+--------------------+---+---+---+
|          1|[1.0,2.0]           |  1|  1|  0|
|          2|[2.0]               |  0|  1|  0|
|          3|[1.0]               |  1|  0|  0|
|          4|[1.0,3.0]           |  1|  0|  1|
+-----------+--------------------+---+---+---+
```

I have tried CountVectorizer(), but could not get the needed output. This example is a sample for the data that I have.

Comment: What did you try with the CountVectorizer? Is [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40306776/18159603) what you are looking for? It is in Scala but it shouldn't be hard to convert to python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a solution for one-hot encoding from a column of lists of categories.

**In Pandas**

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'col1': list(range(1,5)), 'lists': [[1.0,2.0], [2.0],[1.0],[1.0,3.0]]}
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)
df
# Out:
#    col1       lists
# 0     1  [1.0, 2.0]
# 1     2       [2.0]
# 2     3       [1.0]
# 3     4  [1.0, 3.0]

s = df['lists'].explode()
df[['col1']].join(pd.crosstab(s.index, s))
# Out: 
#    col1  1.0  2.0  3.0
# 0     1    1    1    0
# 1     2    0    1    0
# 2     3    1    0    0
# 3     4    1    0    1
```

In Pyspark

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import *

spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
sparkDF = spark.createDataFrame(df) # spark is the Spark session
sparkDF.show()
# Out:
# +----+----------+
# |col1|     lists|
# +----+----------+
# |   1|[1.0, 2.0]|
# |   2|     [2.0]|
# |   3|     [1.0]|
# |   4|[1.0, 3.0]|
# +----+----------+

sparkDF2 = sparkDF.select(sparkDF.col1,explode(sparkDF.lists).alias('newcol'))
sparkDF2.show()
# Out:
# +----+------+
# |col1|newcol|
# +----+------+
# |   1|   1.0|
# |   1|   2.0|
# |   2|   2.0|
# |   3|   1.0|
# |   4|   1.0|
# |   4|   3.0|
# +----+------+

sparkDF.join(sparkDF2.crosstab('col1', 'newcol').withColumnRenamed('col1_newcol','col1'), 'col1').show()
# Out:
# +----+----------+---+---+---+
# |col1|     lists|1.0|2.0|3.0|
# +----+----------+---+---+---+
# |   1|[1.0, 2.0]|  1|  1|  0|
# |   2|     [2.0]|  0|  1|  0|
# |   3|     [1.0]|  1|  0|  0|
# |   4|[1.0, 3.0]|  1|  0|  1|
# +----+----------+---+---+---+
```

Note that this assumes that the lists contain unique categories, if a category is repeated in a list then its count will appear due to `crosstab`.

For example, if sparkDF is

```
+----+---------------+
|col1|          lists|
+----+---------------+
|   1|     [1.0, 2.0]|
|   2|          [2.0]|
|   3|          [1.0]|
|   4|[1.0, 3.0, 3.0]|
+----+---------------+
           ^^^^^^^^^^
```

then the result is:

```
+----+---------------+---+---+---+
|col1|          lists|1.0|2.0|3.0|
+----+---------------+---+---+---+
|   1|     [1.0, 2.0]|  1|  1|  0|
|   2|          [2.0]|  0|  1|  0|
|   3|          [1.0]|  1|  0|  0|
|   4|[1.0, 3.0, 3.0]|  1|  0|  2|
+----+---------------+---+---+---+
                              ^^^^
```

This can be adjusted with a simple transformation.

Comment: i have a solution in pandas, need a pyspark version.

Comment: @butragueno I added a similar solution in pyspark

Comment: this code worked, but when i have values more than 9.0, the column names are coming out as |0.0|1.0|10.0|11.0|12.0|13.0|14.0|15.0|16.0|17.0|18.0|19.0|2.0|20.0|
but should be 0.0|1.0|2.0|3.0|....|10.0|11.0...

Comment: @butragueno you can change the order of the columns with `select`. I would change the names of the categories in the original dataframe because the period `.`  in column names might cause problems later

Comment: i meant the column names after the transformation are not naturally sorted.

Comment: @butragueno they're sorted as strings and not as numbers since column names are strings

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244657/discussion-between-butragueno-and-user2314737).

Answer (score 1):

```
import more_itertools as mit
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'columnIndex': [1, 2, 3, 4], 'lists': [[1.0, 2.0], [2.0], [1.0], [1.0, 3.0]]})
df = pd.concat([df, pd.DataFrame(columns=[1, 2, 3])])
df[[1, 2, 3]] = [0, 0, 0]

for i in range(0, len(df['lists'])):
    index = list(mit.locate([1, 2, 3], lambda x: x in df.loc[i, 'lists']))
    index = np.array(index) + 1
    df.loc[i, index] = 1
```

Output

```
   columnIndex       lists  1  2  3
0          1.0  [1.0, 2.0]  1  1  0
1          2.0       [2.0]  0  1  0
2          3.0       [1.0]  1  0  0
3          4.0  [1.0, 3.0]  1  0  1
```

I can offer as an option based on pandas. First, the missing columns with values of 0 are created. Further, based on the column numbers, indexes are obtained for setting values. Note that 1 is added to the indexes.